# CSV data upload via API?

Tags: looker-studio, google-data-api

We currently have a manual process by which we export a report to CSV from our current issue tracking system (YouTrack currently).  We then upload this file to GDS, which results in a report that we share with clients (internal and external).

Is there GDS API support for the "upload CSV to build/refresh the report" step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported. However, you can try one uploading your data to one of the following sources and then create a Data Studio dashboard from that source:

- Google Sheets
- BigQuery
- MySQL/PostgreSQL

Each of these will provide some type of API support for uploading CSVs.